# Terms of $\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} \frac{\eta^{q}e^{q}}{q^{q(1-\beta)}}$ tend to 0 more rapidly than terms of any geometric progression?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Could anyone explain to me this reasoning in a part of a proof?

$$\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} \frac{\eta^{q}e^{q}}{q^{q(1-\beta)}}$$

"Since the terms of the series tend to zero more rapidly than the terms of any geometric progression, then starting with some number the $q$-th term of the series becomes less than $\frac{1}{2^{q}}$."

How do I see that they tend more rapidly to zero than terms of a geometric progression?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that $\beta <1 $

Comment: Prove $$\lim_{q\to\infty}\frac{a^q}{q^{q(1-\beta)}} = 0$$ for any $a>0$.  But you will need some information about $\beta$.  What will you need?

Comment: Yeah, I edited my post. Yeah I see that this goes to 0, but not sure why more rapidly than any geometric progression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning explained: For any *fixed* positive number $A$ and any $\beta < 1$, there is a $q'(A)$ s.t. the inequality

$$q^{(1-\beta)q} > A^q$$

holds for all $q  \ge q'(A)$; namely all $q \ge A^{\frac{1}{1-\beta}}+1 = q'(A)$. [Indeed, taking natural log on both sides of the inequality $q^{(1-\beta)q} > A^q$ and dividing by $1-\beta$ gives $$q \ln q > \frac{q \ln A }{1-\beta}.$$ Dividing by $q$ on each side of this gives $$\ln q > \frac{\ln A}{1-\beta}.$$ Then exponentiating both sides of this gives $$q > A^{\frac{1}{1-\beta}}.$$ Note that one can reverse the steps here to show that the strict inequality $q^{(1-\beta)q}  > A^q$ is satisfied if the strict inequality $q > A^{\frac{1}{1-\beta}}$ is satisfied,  so $A^{\frac{1}{1-\beta}}+1 = q'(A)$ will do.]

So to show that there is a $q'$ such that $\frac{\eta^q e^q}{q^{(1-\beta)q}} < 2^{-q}$ for all $q' \ge q$, take $A = 2 \eta e$; then the inequality $q^{(1-\beta)q} < A^q = 2^q \eta^q e^q$ holds for all $q \ge q'(A)$:

$$\frac{\eta^q e^q}{q^{(1-\beta)q}} = \frac{2^{-q}A^q}{q^{(1-\beta)q}} = 2^{-q}\left(\frac{A^q}{q^{(1-\beta)q}}\right) < 2^{-q}.$$

Comment: Hmm I don't really see how you came up with the value of $q'(A)$

Comment: I revised my answer w an explanation.

Comment: In the last inequality there should be an equal sign instead of < right?

Comment: I just editted that to the correct answer.